# Git Push failing due to missing files

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I just came across a known error with Eclipse/Glassfish in a project I am working on. Basically, Eclipse/Glassfish are somehow getting confused, and refuses to launch my Web Application. A full re-install of eclipse and glassfish still gives me the same problem when I use my project files from the github repository.

So I had to delete the repository locally, and then create a new Eclipse project with all the same code files in it. Now Eclipse/Glassfish runs the new project smoothly, and I want to update the remote repository with the new project.

However, when I do the command in git bash:

```
git push origin master
```

I get the following error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:......"
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull....') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So basically this is telling me to do a pull before i do the push. But I really don't want to do a pull, as it contains some eclipse stuff that is causing the problem that I spent hours trying to fix.

What command do I need to do, that will push the current files I have to the remote repository, and at the same time, get rid of those that don't exist locally from the remote repository? I don't mind so much if they exist in previous commits, but just not from the current one onwards....

All help much appreciated.

Comment: what's your repository host? what about creating the repository again? a forced push?, check the difference between the last commit of your server repo and your current working directory? push only that?. It's easy to say that "it has no solution" when you tried nothing but a single command.

Comment: Let me re-word that - I meant the no known solution was for the eclipse/glassfish part..... not the git part.... apologies

Answer (score 0):

You can **by your own risk** force the push.

```
git push origin master --force
```

You will overwrite the files on origin.

> ...This flag disables these checks, and can cause the remote repository
>   to lose commits; use it with care.

Documentation:

[git-push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Comment: This will overwrite the files, but will delete all the previous commits, right? Any way to do it without losing the previous commits?

Comment: The pending commits that git suggests you to pull (to update your local branch), yes.
Maybe you can make a new branch with the current files and start to include the new commits one by one, using cherry-pick and testing the project after each new commit to see what is causing the problem.